# android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-adapter

When using android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder in our adapter, does it require view tagging as we do earlier.
Or is the library does it automatically in back end ?

Comment: `onBindViewHolder` will do the binding, so no need tagging

Answer (score 1):

You don't need view.setTag(viewHolder), just bind data in onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position).
PS: You should edit the title of your question to describe more about your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to tag the View with the ViewHolder anymore if you are also extending `RecyclerView.Adapter` in your Adapter. The RecyclerView adapter requires you to implement a few methods, which guide you to create and bind the view holder.

- `onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)` which is where you inflate the View and create the ViewHolder - the constructor for RecyclerView.ViewHolder requires you to pass in the View.
- `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int i)` where you perform all the operations you need to bind the data to the holder
- `getItemCount()` to return the number of items in your RecyclerView

The adapter should look something like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ...
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        // TODO: inflate your view and create viewholder, most likely looks like this though
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.recycler_view_item,
            viewGroup,
            false);

        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        // TODO: all your bind operations
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        // TODO: return total item count of your views
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // TODO: whatever views you need to bind
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ImageView mImageView;

        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v); // done this way instead of view tagging
            mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
            mImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot do this!  You will get an error: `viewHolder is abstract; cannot be instantiated`

Comment: you are probably instantiating `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` rather than the custom ViewHolder declared in the inner static class. I will edit the example to make that clearer.